# Wireless network w/access to the internet from another wireless network

Tags: wireless-networking

The complex I live in has a wireless network providing internet service to the whole complex.  Trouble is, it only allows one device connected to it per apartment.  To connect to it from a computer, you have to enter a code via your web browser before you can access the internet, then that device is registered on their system as your one authorized device.

I'd like to set up a wireless network in my apartment that:

- draws its access to the internet from the complex-wide wireless network
- is WPA-protected and firewall-protected, independently of any security that the complex's network offers between it and the outside world

Here's how it looks now:

[image: how it is now]

And here's how I want it to be:

[image: how I want it to be]

If it's important, I currently have a brand new Linksys N600 router available.

(And this isn't some way to try and cheat the complex's network rules; the manager actually suggested I set up my own local network, she just didn't know how one would do that.)

Comment: Travel routers are often explicitly designed for this:  http://lifehacker.com/five-best-travel-routers-1452441479

Comment: Most router are like this.  It's the same reason you can plug a router into a modem

Comment: @ramhound : yes, but he wants wifi on both the WAN and LAN sides

Comment: You can also get a "wireless bridge".  Basically a device that converts your apt's wifi connection into a wired one... Then your existing router can use that wired ethernet connection just as it would a connection coming from a cable modem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to purchase a router than offers both wireless (Wifi) WAN & LAN simultaneously.
My favourite brand is TP-Link, affordable and reliable with a 3 year warranty.

Something like this would be suitable:
http://www.tp-link.com.au/products/details/?categoryid=1246&model=TL-WR843ND#fea