# How can a router log in to a wireless network that requires an in-browser password?

Tags: wireless-networking

At our apartment complex there's a wi-fi network for all the residents.

- There's no password to access the network itself (no WPA password, for example).  Instead, there's a password that you have to enter using your browser in order to access the internet.
- Each apartment can only log on with one device.

I'm planning to set up a wireless network in my home that lets me connect multiple devices to it (as described in my [earlier question](https://superuser.com/questions/730684)).  How can my router / wireless repeater become the one device connected to the complex's network, since it doesn't have a browser interface to enter a password in.

In short,

**How can my router enter an in-browser password?**

*(Strange idea)*  Could I log in with my laptop, then tell my router to change its MAC address to match my laptop's?  Would that cause a problem, for my laptop and wirelss router to have the same MAC address?

Comment: Just a thought on your "Strange idea", it would be better to spoof your router's mac from your computer, authenticate, and then disconnect and connect the router (that is assuming it is determined based on MAC) and not against the TOS.  That avoids your proposed issue.

Comment: May be a good place to use internet connection sharing (ICS) in windows.