# How To Obtain IP from Public Wireless Router and Share via My Own Private Wireless Router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, nat

I live in an apartment with a public wireless router which requires you to log in via a splash-screen page.

I want to have my own private wireless router which logs into the public wireless router once, obtains an IP address, and then shares that IP address freely for use within my own private LAN. This way my devices can use the private router without having to log into the splash screen of the public router.

I have a TL-WR841N for my private router. How can I pull this off?

Edit:

The TL-WR841N is v9 so I don't think I can use open wrt or dd-wrt.

Edit 2:

I found this program Virtual Router (https://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/) which seems to do the job just using a laptop with only 1 WiFi adapter. However it appears the bandwidth gets halved, which is expected.

My new plan is to use a USB WiFi adapter, giving the laptop 2 Wifi adapters, and then sharing the internet connection from one on the other via an ad-hoc network. I believe it will be important that both adapters are on **non-overlapping frequencies as to prevent collisions.** I'm hoping this doesn't halve the bandwidth like the Virtual Router does.

Comment: Weird, someone else JUST asked this question here: [How can a router log in to a wireless network that requires an in-browser password?](http://superuser.com/questions/731187/how-can-a-router-log-in-to-a-wireless-network-that-requires-an-in-browser-passwo)

Answer (score 0):

Put simply, you cant.

However you can use a computer to bridge the connections to share the internet on your internal network.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to have purchased a usb wifi adapter that can operate in Access Mode ([like this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003MTTJOY)) and have installed it in your computer.  Then, assuming you're on Windows 7, open `Network and Sharing Center`.

Select `Set up a new connection or network`.

Follow the directions in the wizard, selecting `Set up a wireless ad-hoc (computer-to-computer) network`.  Give it a name and password.  Make sure to check the checkbox "Save this network" or you'll end up doing this step again after a reboot.

Now you should be able to connect to your new network but will have no internet.

Back in `Network and Sharing Center`, select `Change adapter settings`, open the properties on the network adapter where the internet is come **from** (not the new adapter you installed), in the `Share` tab, enable internet connection sharing.

You should now be able to connect to your PC and piggy back the internet connection your PC is enjoying.

This is the easy way, if this doesn't work for you, let me know and I'll post the "hard" way.  I had to go the more involved route to get my android phone to connect.

Source:  [Turn Your Windows PC Into a Wireless Hotspot](http://lifehacker.com/5369381/turn-your-windows-7-pc-into-a-wireless-hotspot)